# SDWebImage with FIRStorage in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous, sdwebimage

I have a take that get images from FIRebase Storage. But it is changing the images while I scroll up and down in the table view. I tried all the thing s over the internet and stack overflow, but no luck. Below is my code.

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "dataObj.h"
#import "MZFormSheetPresentationViewControllerSegue.h"
#import "BrowseTableViewController.h"
#import "FavouritesTableViewController.h"
#import "ProfileObj.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "InboxTableViewController.h"
#import "ProfileViewController.h"

#import <KeychainItemWrapper/KeychainItemWrapper.h>

@import SDWebImage;
@import FirebaseDatabaseUI;
@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseAuthUI;
@import FirebaseGoogleAuthUI;
@import FirebaseFacebookAuthUI;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier;
    CustomCell *cell;
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        cellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }else{

    cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
FIRStorage *storage = [FIRStorage storage];
    FIRStorageReference *storageRef = [[storage reference] child:@"publicListings"];

    if([photo0 intValue] == 1){
        FIRStorageReference *idRef = [storageRef child:self.snaps.key];
        FIRStorageReference *folderRef = [idRef child:@"photos"];
        NSString *fileName = @"photo0.jpg";
        FIRStorageReference *imageRef = [folderRef child:fileName];
        [imageRef downloadURLWithCompletion:^(NSURL *URL, NSError *error){
            if(error != nil){
                NSLog(@"%@",error);
            }
            else{
                [cell.imgPhoto sd_setImageWithURL:URL
                             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"]
                                      options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

//                NSString *url = URL.absoluteString;
//                [cell.imgPhoto sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
            }
        }];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TableViewCell is reusable and you may get a dequeued cell which has been used, try clear cell state after you got a cell.

In your case, try set

```
cell.imgPhoto = nil;
```

or

```
cell.imgPhoto = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];
```

before use this cell.

Comment: Where should I put the above code line? Just before  [cell.imgPhoto sd_setImageWithURL:URL
                             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"]
                                      options:SDWebImageRefreshCached]; or after that?

Comment: after you got a cell

Comment: Even so you should always clear your reusable cell to initial states. And try to remove SDWebImageRefreshCached option if your url is unique for each photo.